# Playing raw audio PCM samples in Web Audio

Tags: javascript, audio, buffer, web-audio-api, arraybuffer

I have an array of sound samples (16-bit):

```
[0, 120, 320, 120, 0, -100, -30000, 65, 2, 3, 10, ...]
```

They range -32768 to 32767. I would like to be able to play the samples using the Web Audio API.

I know that it expects the source buffer to be an `ArrayBuffer`, but I can't quite figure out how to convert a bunch of samples to an `ArrayBuffer` to be played with the Web Audio API.

Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a new AudioContext, use CreateBuffer to create an AudioBuffer of the right length and number of channels, and then use getChannelData to access the bits - then run through a loop that for each sample sets the bufferData[i] = (original_data[i] / 32768);